Failed to resolve the Android SDK path - React-native using WSL-2
I am trying to launch a react-native app on my Android device which is plugged into a laptop via USB.
I am getting this error when running the following commands:
$ npm start
$ a

which should launch the android app on the USB device:

Failed to resolve the Android SDK path. Default install location not
found: /home/myusername/Android/sdk. Use ANDROID_HOME to set the
Android SDK location.

My current setup has the following unique properties:

I am running react-native inside WSL2 on a Windows device
The only way I have managed to get adb device to recognise my phone is by downloading the platform-tools for Windows as in this stack post, and then adding a symlink to the adb.exe file inside the folder, as so: sudo ln -s /mnt/c/platform-tools/adb.exe /usr/bin/adb

It is worth noting that the Expo Go app is successfully installed and launched in the phone as a result of switching to android mode (by executing the $ a command above). So I suspect this is the final step in managing to get the app to launch on the phone.
Can someone offer any advice on how to resolve the Android SDK error?
So far I have found that I have an Android SDK folder in this location on Windows (thanks to this stack post). But I don't know at this stage whether it is correct to try and set the SDK location to that Windows path, or if I am supposed to set it to a WSL2 path instead.
I did copy the platform-tools folder to /mnt/c/Users/myusername/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk, as it was previously missing. But if it's a simple case of pointing towards that directory for a successful launch then I would love to know how to do that as well!
Is this really a unique case given the WSL2 setup, or is it simply that I need to install Android Studio like in this stack post?

WSL is pretty simply: what you want to use inside, install inside (and don't forget to use the Linux version).
